# constructing a std::function object from a type with a variadic template constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, variadic-templates, std-function, copy-assignment

I have a templated class which instantiates an internal object of the template type and its constructor forwards the arguments to the internal object.

```
template<typename T>
struct B
{
    template<typename... Args>
    B(Args&&... args) : m(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    
    B(const B& b) = default;
    B(B&& b) noexcept = default;

    void operator()() { m(); }
    
    T m;
};
```

Also this class is callable and it simply delegates the call to its internal member.
The reason it is callable is because I want to pass it around as a std::function.
The problem is that the compiler doesn't let me initialize a std::function with an object of type B:

```
struct A
{
    void operator()() { std::cout << "A()\n"; }
};

void foo()
{
    B<A> b;
    std::function<void()> fb = b; //Error
}
```

The error is a cryptic one:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(B&)’
     B(Args&&... args) : a(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

Nowhere in my code have I made a call to A::A(B&).
I expect std::function to call B::B(B&) constructor to copy the data from **b** to **fb**.

Note that this only happens because of the variadic template constructor of B.
The following code compiles fine:

```
A a;
std::function<void()> fa = a;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instantion of

```
template<typename... Args>
B(Args&&... args)
```

with `Args... == B&` is a better match for copying a non-const lvalue `B` than either your copy or move constructor. Instantiating that is like

```
B(B& args) : m(args) {}
```

which uses `A::A(B&)`

You could either add an overload `B(B&) = default;`, or add some SFINAE to your template constructor.

Comment: I didn't mention this, but in the original code I was passing B<A> as an rvalue reference like this: ```std::function<void()> fb { B<A>{} };``` and I thought that the rvalue overload would be selected.
However, I didn't consider one thing. My original A class has virtual methods and this somehow changes the overload resolution.
So it seems that if class A has virtual methods the only solution is what you suggested: non-const lvalue reference, or SFINAE.
If class A didn't have virtual methods, simply passing rvalue reference or slapping const would have fixed the issue.

Comment: @ЗамфирЙончев you also have to consider the copy members of `std::function` which will want to copy `B`s